# jira-python hanging on request on Windows without any kind of failure or notification

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

My script returns changelog history for `JIRA` tickets, and it seems to work fine on my dev machine (Mac Pro).  It hung a few times when I tried to implement async to pull the requests faster, but with a single threaded process it works every time.

When I deployed on our Windows production server, it reaches about the 90% completion point, and then hangs without any kind of helpful message or indication what might be going wrong.  The Windows Task Scheduler shows it as "complete", which means that it must be returning some kind of successful completion code that isn't outwardly visible.  I'm a bit confused as to where to even start tracking down the cause of this issue.  I'll include my code for reference:

```
# jira_changelog_history.py
"""
Records the history for every jira issue ID in a database.
"""
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from csv import DictWriter
import datetime
import gzip
import logging
from threading import Lock
from typing import Generator

from jira import JIRA

from inst_config import config3, jira_config as jc
from inst_utils import aws_utils
from inst_utils.inst_oauth import SigMethodRSA
from inst_utils.jira_utils import JiraOauth
from inst_utils.misc_utils import (
    add_etl_fields,
    clean_data,
    get_fieldnames,
    initialize_logger
)

TODAY = datetime.date.today()

logger = initialize_logger(config3.GET_LOGFILE(
    # r'C:\Runlogs\JiraChangelogHistory\{date}.txt'.format(
    #     date=TODAY
    # )
    'logfile.txt'
)
)


def return_jira_keys(
        jira_instance: JIRA,
        jql: str,
        result_list: list,
        start_at: int,
        max_res: int = 500
) -> Generator:
    issues = jira_instance.search_issues(
        jql_str=jql,
        startAt=start_at,
        maxResults=max_res,
        fields='key'
    )
    for issue in issues:
        result_list.append(issue.key)


def write_issue_history(
        jira_instance: JIRA,
        issue_id: str,
        writer: DictWriter,
        lock: Lock):
    logging.debug('Now processing data for issue {}'.format(issue_id))
    changelog = jira_instance.issue(issue_id, expand='changelog').changelog

    for history in changelog.histories:
        created = history.created
        for item in history.items:
            to_write = dict(issue_id=issue_id)
            to_write['date'] = created
            to_write['field'] = item.field
            to_write['changed_from'] = item.fromString
            to_write['changed_to'] = item.toString
            clean_data(to_write)
            add_etl_fields(to_write)
            with lock:
                writer.writerow(to_write)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        signature_method = SigMethodRSA(jc.JIRA_RSA_KEY_PATH)
        o = JiraOauth(jc.OAUTH_URLS, jc.CONSUMER_INFO, signature_method)
        req_pub = o.oauth_dance_part1()
        o.gain_authorization(jc.AUTHORIZATION_URL, req_pub)
        acc_pub, acc_priv = o.oauth_dance_part2()

        with open(jc.JIRA_RSA_KEY_PATH) as key_f:
            key_data = key_f.read()

        oauth_dict = {
            'access_token': acc_pub,
            'access_token_secret': acc_priv,
            'consumer_key': config3.CONSUMER_KEY,
            'key_cert': key_data
        }
        j = JIRA(
            server=config3.BASE_URL,
            oauth=oauth_dict
        )
        # Full load
        # jql = 'project not in ("IT Service Desk")'
        # 3 day load, need SQL statement to trunc out if key in
        jql = 'project not in ("IT Service Desk") AND updatedDate > -3d'

        # "total" attribute of JIRA.ReturnedList returns the total records
        total_records = j.search_issues(jql, maxResults=1).total
        logging.info('Total records: {total}'.format(total=total_records))
        start_at = tuple(range(0, total_records, 500))
        keys = []

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exec:
            for start in start_at:
                exec.submit(return_jira_keys, j, jql, keys, start)

        table = r'ods_jira.staging_jira_changelog_history'
        fieldnames = get_fieldnames(
            table_name=table,
            db_info=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD
        )
        # loadfile = (
        #     r'C:\etl3\file_staging\jira_changelog_history\{date}.csv.gz'.format(
        #         date=TODAY
        #     ))
        loadfile = r'jira_changelogs.csv.gz'
        with gzip.open(loadfile, 'wt') as outf:
            writer = DictWriter(
                f=outf,
                fieldnames=fieldnames,
                delimiter='|',
                extrasaction='ignore'
            )
            writer_lock = Lock()
            for index, key in enumerate(keys):
                logging.info(
                    'On #{num} of {total}: %{percent_done:.2f} '
                    'completed'.format(
                        num=index,
                        total=total_records,
                        percent_done=(index / total_records) * 100
                    ))
                write_issue_history(
                    jira_instance=j,
                    issue_id=key,
                    writer=writer,
                    lock=writer_lock
                )

                # with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as exec:
                #     for key in keys:
                #         exec.submit(
                #             write_issue_history,
                #             j,
                #             key,
                #             writer,
                #             writer_lock
                #         )

        s3 = aws_utils.S3Loader(
            infile=loadfile,
            s3_filepath='jira_scripts/changelog_history/'
        )
        s3.load()
        rs = aws_utils.RedshiftLoader(
            table_name=table,
            safe_load=True
        )
        delete_stmt = '''
          DELETE FROM {table_name}
          WHERE issue_id in {id_list}
        '''.format(
            table_name=table,
            id_list=(
                '('
                + ', '.join(['\'{}\''.format(key) for key in keys])
                + ')')
        )
        rs.execute(
            rs.use_custom_sql,
            sql=delete_stmt
        )
        rs.execute(
            rs.copy_to_db,
            copy_from=s3.get_full_destination()
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a single worker to see if that works better

Comment: So the part with 5 workers is working flawlessly (it just returns a list of issue ID's), it's the sequential part underneath `for index, key in enumerate(keys):` that is getting stuck.  So it's only using a single thread when it's processing that part.

Comment: Sometimes there is oddness with issues that have been deleted or moved to another project. For example if an issue was moved to a more restricted project would it return an error about not being visible?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that.  I guess what is confusing is that it works on the Mac but not on Windows for the exact same set of issue ID's.

Comment: That is odd. Must be something platform specific in the Python libraries used